# how to get to data outside a docker container?

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow docker image to run my code
I have pulled the `tensorflow:tensorflow:1.6.0-gpu-py3` container
I have a python code exist on my machine
I used the `-v` flag in order to mount the directory where my code exist using the following:

```
-v host-dir:working_dir -w working directory
```

Therefore I was able to run any python file exist in that dir using the command:

```
sudo docker run --gpus all -it --rm -v /media/data:/home/user/Downloads/tmp -w /home/wseam/Downloads/tmp tensorflow/tensorflow:1.6.0-gpu-py3 python ./TheCode/train.py
```

the problem is that inside my python file I am trying to get some data `.tf_records` from another dir exist inside the mounted one, I am using `assert os.path.isdir(wanted_dir)`
after I try to run the command I get assertion error regarding the `wanted_dir`.

I do not know maybe the mounting method using `-v` flag affects.

Comment: If you replace `./TheCode/train.py` with `bash` in your docker run command, you will start a shell session in the container. It's easier to investigate these kind of issues in a shell. It could be a typo, or a permission thing.

Comment: Thanks dear i will give it a chance

Answer (score 1):

You are probably making a mistake when you mount the volumes in your docker command. I think you want `-v /home/user/Downloads/tmp:/media/data` instead of what you wrote. The first term is the location on your file system and the second one is the location inside the container. The problem is that I don't think that docker will object if the path is not defined in the container but Python certainly will, when you will try to create some files.

Comment: Dear the mout way I did is true like you said the first term is the dir where my code exist and the second one is the container dir

Comment: And have you verified that `/home/user/Downloads/tmp` exists in your container? Because that will pose a problem if you are trying to mount something to an unexisting location.

Comment: no dear the tmp dir exist outside the container but I have changed the working dir of the image to the tmp dir ...now I am trying something else I create the volume for the container and I am trying moving my code and data to that volume